# The pattern with main-stressed "it is" at the end as in "I'd like a burger please. - Ok, a burger it is."

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning and the proper way of using the said pattern? Does it have variations?

Here is another instance from Interstellar:

- Hey, TARS, what's your honesty parameter?
- 90%.
- Ok. 90% it is, Dr. Brand.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of ["fronting"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/fronting) a predicate nominative.<sup>1</sup> Normally the sentences would be:

> It is **a burger**.
> It is **90%**.

Elements may be fronted for emphasis, for variety, for clarity, etc. In your examples I think that the main reason is for emphasis; after all, "it is" does not contain much information (and could even be omitted entirely) while "a burger" and "90%" contain the important information.

The most obvious variation would be to use a different pronoun and a different form of "to be", e.g.:

> A: Those clouds look like elephants.
> B: No, they look like swans.
> A: OK, then **swans** they are.

Various other elements can be fronted, too, though. Here is a predicate adjective:

> A: The answer is 5.
> B: **Right** you are!

And here is a direct object:

> A: I'd like a burger, please.
> B: Well, if it's a burger you want, then **a burger** you get.

---

<sup>1</sup>I consider 90% to be a noun phrase here, not an adjective phrase.

Answer (score 1):

This is an OSV (object, subject, verb) sentence created with **object fronting**:

> **That car** we bought at least five years ago. **The other one** we only bought last year. (By fronting the objects (**that car** and **the other one**) we focus on them and the contrast between them.)
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus_2)

The purpose of the sentences in your example are to confirm what was just said.

It would make no sense to use SVO in your examples instead; you can't say "it is [noun phrase]". (I can't think of another context right now that requires fronting like that.)